# Inline-block vs inline elements in terms of line-breaks

Tags: html, css

Inside of a parent element which is a paragraph, there is text and a couple of anchor links. These anchor links have their display set to `inline-block` and the visual result looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgAzv.jpg

Now if I would change the display to inline, the result looks like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfXSE.jpg

My question is, why does having the display of the anchors set to `inline-block` instead of just `inline` cause this, let's just say "soft line break" ? Because I thought that in terms of line-breaks, both of the displays act in the same way, and don't break at all.

Codepen link for the code: https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/zpvmYV

The code for the parent element:

```
.footer__copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid #777;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}
```

The code for the anchors:

```
footer__link:link, .footer__link:visited {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    background-color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

The anchors are:

```
<a href="#" class="footer__link">Jonas Schmedtmann</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" class="footer__link">Advanced CSS and Sass</a>
```

Comment: An `inline-block` cannot be broken across lines; it behaves as if it was a large letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line break happens because the the inline block cannot be split across multiple lines like a normal inline element. It is simply one entire "block unit" that is displayed inline. If that entire unit does not fit, then it will all be wrapped down to the next line.